# Нужна ли запятая? Если нужна, то подскажите правило, пожалуйста

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Имеют носовой фиксатор и ушные резинки(,) закрепленные ультразвуковой сваркой.

Comment: Ну вообще-то это классе в восьмом объясняют, что причастный оборот требует обособления.

Answer (score 1):

Нужна. Запятая открывает причастный оборот, заканчивающийся точкой (конец предложения).

---

> Причастный оборот – синтаксическая конструкция, состоящая из причастия
> и зависимых от него слов. В предложении причастный оборот всегда
> является определением (обособленным или необособленным). При
> употреблении причастного оборота запятые могут ставиться с двух сторон
> оборота либо не ставиться, в зависимости от его позиции по отношению к
> определяемому слову.
>
> Чтобы правильно расставить запятые в предложении с причастным
> оборотом, нужно предварительно определить его границы, поставив вопрос
> от определяемого слова. Определяемое слово в состав причастного
> оборота не входит.

[Когда причастный оборот выделяется запятыми в предложении?](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/prichastnyy-oborot)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Минус - за ссылку на некачественный источник.  Неужели Вы не видите, насколько неудачны там примеры и формулировки? А человек и без того азбучных истин не знает.

Comment: Спасибо! Человек обещает познать азбучные истины.